# Wordpress - Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this item

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, https, themes

I've got weird error message on one of my site after moving to a new hosting

> Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this item.

What I found as solutions and didn't work for me is:

1. I checked all the prefix stuff since my perfix isnt `wp_` so everything is accurate in `users_meta`, also in `wp_options`.
2. I even tried inserting new administration user with php code, I got the same error.
3. I also tried deactivating all the plugins & resetting to default theme but nothing worked.

The server i'm moved on to has ssl, so its https conenction which is covered with updates of all urls inside db.

Another issue is when i logged in `wp-admin` it shows same message

> Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this item.

In the front-end I see the fully functional wp-bar with all buttons edit page/Create New post/page/etc. But when I click it shows same error as above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you updated your SQL database with the new `https` url?

Comment: Yes, i did. Every url in the database is with https.

Comment: When did you moved the website?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to edit a Page/Post, or do you get the error before you even see the WP Dashboard? Sounds like the error on the front-end as well, does the site itself work or do you only see the error?

Comment: I had a site with this error. Turned out nearly every table had the Auto-Increment flag turned off and many were missing the Primary Key flag as well. I also found duplicate data in the Primary Key column. I fixed the tables manually using MyPHP Admin. I've seen SQL queries that should work more efficently.

Answer (score 7):

If you're trying to edit Categories/Custom taxonomies and you get this error, you should be doing the following.

1. Check the `wp_term_taxonomy` table for Term IDs that are associated with more than one Taxonomy ID. These records are the root cause for the error. The following query should help you find that.

   ```
   SELECT term_id, COUNT(term_id) FROM wp_term_taxonomy GROUP BY term_id HAVING COUNT(term_id) > 1;
   ```
2. Check for the `taxonomy` column in the `wp_term_taxonomy` table that you would like to retain and delete the other `taxonomy` record. Before deleting refer #3.
3. You should also be deleting records from `wp_term_relationships` table for the corresponding `term_taxonomy_id` that you're deleting from the `wp_term_taxonomy` table.

**Tip:**
Back up your database before executing any DELETE queries on your database.

Comment: @Dragomir Ivanov, @Arsalan Mithani Adding the following line - `if (is_admin()) return true;` could potentially lead to security leaks.

Comment: This saved me some serious time, Maria. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate All your plugin and Activate them one by one it will help to find the culprit. if you are not able to get into the dashboard use FTP and rename plugins directory.

**Temporary Fix - Recommended for staging only**

i've found a temporary fix is to edit `wp-includes/capabilities.php`

Replace this code

```
function current_user_can( $capability ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( empty( $current_user ) )
        return false;

    $args = array_slice( func_get_args(), 1 );
    $args = array_merge( array( $capability ), $args );

    return call_user_func_array( array( $current_user, 'has_cap' ), $args );
}
```

With This

```
function current_user_can( $capability ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( empty( $current_user ) )
        return false;

    if (is_admin())
        return true;
    $args = array_slice( func_get_args(), 1 );
    $args = array_merge( array( $capability ), $args );

    return call_user_func_array( array( $current_user, 'has_cap' ), $args );
}
```

**That's just a temporary fix. If it works, you will still have to find appropriate solution as `capabilities.php` is core file & any update will override your code.**

Comment: This is a very bad solution. Aside from editing core it removes all capability-checks - and there will be no difference between the user roles.

Comment: Thank you Mathani, you were the only writer on the internet who actually explained where the security check was taking place. This allowed me to temporarily suspend the check to fix a corrupt administrator profile. I used 'return true;' to effectively suspend the function and allow dashboard access, Turned it back on afterwards, naturally.

Comment: NEVER edit core files as you'll lose every change you made when you update WordPress to a newer version.

Comment: @mukto90 it is clearly stated in the end already what you said in your comment. It only shows where the check is taking place. Let me **highlight** it

Comment: Agreed, this isn't a solution to this problem. However this is exactly what I needed to bypass this error on my local dev environment. I just added an `if ( 'local' === wp_get_environment_type() ) return true;`